# New activity fragment pattern for Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

Since many months, I as an android developer, am using Activity-Fragment pattern for the implementation of Activity. But it seems that Google decided to change the pattern (Again).

Few days back I updated Android studio to v1.4 beta 4. I noticed a new pattern for Activity build up. When I tried to create the new activity from new->Activity, I could not find "New Activity with blank fragment". Instead, there were two new options "Empty Activity" and "Blank Activity". [image]
 I opted Blank Activity and had following files inserted.

1. MainActivity.java (Activity class)
   [image: mainActivity.java file]
2. activity_main.xml (layout of activity)
   [image: activity_main.xml file]
3. content_main.xml (content of activity included by activtiy_main.xml)
   [image: content_main.xml file]

So my question is, what is the new pattern for development that Android developer should follow?

----EDIT----
**How to use the previous pattern of Activity-Fragment**
To get 'Fragment' back into picture you need to select "use a fragment" in dialog that appears after selecting "Blank Activity"
[image]

Comment: what does it have to to with using Fragments in your code?

Comment: Android developer should not following any pattern because every  week new changes are coming in the Android OS. Follows what you know but learn new things.

Comment: @pskink, basically Fragment was maintaining instance during orientation.

Comment: @Rustam, surely new changes are coming frequently, but these are the changes that they take release very carefully for developers so that it make the development easier and maintanable.

Comment: *Android developer should not following any pattern* bold statement. Not true of course

Comment: and now you cannot use Fragments? how come?

Comment: @pskink , I can use the fragment no problem with that but the android studio is not giving it now by default as of before. So now they are insisting something else than "Activity-Fragment" way.

Comment: maybe they are trying to discourage developers from using Fragments? i always felt that Fragments smell bad (at least that way they are used by 90% of developers at SO)

Comment: @pskink, yeah mostly you are right that they are discouraging the use of fragment, the new options in android studio shows that.  Along with that maybe they have implemented "AppCompatActivity" in a way that it removes the flaw or limitations of "Activity" and by removing fragment for each n every activity, it makes code more clear.

Comment: I never really liked fragments either seemed an additional file which shouldn't have been needed. Although fragments load waaaaay faster than a new activity when transitioning from page to page. Nobody have a useful link on the new design pattern they obviously want you to follow?